# newtonsoft json parses only 16 significant digits

Tags: c#, json, json.net, precision

When I parse following json:

```
{
    "Item1": 123456789.0123456789,
    "Item2": "123456789.0123456789",
    "Item3": 1.234567890123456789,
    "Item4": 1234567890123456789
}
```

like so:

```
string data = "{\"Item1\":123456789.0123456789,\"Item2\":\"123456789.0123456789\",\"Item3\":1.234567890123456789,\"Item4\":1234567890123456789}";
JObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(data, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None });
Console.WriteLine(json["Item1"].Value<decimal>());
Console.WriteLine(json["Item2"].Value<decimal>());
Console.WriteLine(json["Item3"].Value<decimal>());
Console.WriteLine(json["Item4"].Value<decimal>());
```

then I get following output:

```
123456789,012346
123456789,0123456789
1,23456789012346
1234567890123456789
```

in my actual json data source inputs are like `"name":123456789.0123456789`. How do I parse its whole decimal value without losing precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [FloatParseHandling Enumeration](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm) to instruct it to deserialize to `decimal`:

```
JObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(data, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings { 
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None, 
        FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal // Added new setting
    });
```

(You don't specify which version of Newtonsoft you're using so I assume the latest)